# OpenCV seamlessClone flickering

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-processing

I have a [video](http://vecg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/Projects/AutoCinemagraphs/highway.avi), from which I extract the first frame to use as a static background. For each frame of the video, I would like to mask a part of it on top of the static background, using this [mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRxZn.png).

Without blending:

```
maskedFrame = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask = mask)
maskedBackground = cv2.bitwise_and(staticBackground, staticBackground, mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask))
output = maskedFrame + maskedBackground
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ7qm.jpg)

However, I would like to use Poisson blending:

```
output = cv2.seamlessClone(frame, staticBackground, center, cv2.NORMAL_CLONE)
```

With the center computed like so:

```
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])
center = (int(x+w/2), int(y+h/2))
```

This produces [weird results and flickering, and what looks like a rectangular mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoi6o.jpg).

I thought maybe the mask was too tight around the moving object, so I scaled its contour but that didn't fix the problem. I also tried seamlessClone with maskedBackground instead of staticBackground but, unsurprisingly, that didn't work either.

Is seamlessClone a wrong choice for this problem or am I using it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that seamlessClone inverts the mask after each frame.
It can be fixed by either having a deepcopy of the mask, or inverting the mask after each iteration so it's back to the original one.